# When I set CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True then 403 (Forbidden) error occurred

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf, django-react

In my **settings.py:**

```
...
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

**authenticate.py:**

```
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
    from django.conf import settings
    from rest_framework import exceptions
    from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck

    def enforce_csrf(request):
        """
        Enforce CSRF validation.
        """
        check = CSRFCheck()
        # populates request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'], which is used in process_view()
        check.process_request(request)
        reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})
        print(reason)
        if reason:
            # CSRF failed, bail with explicit error message
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)
    
    class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
        
        def authenticate(self, request):
            .....
            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
            enforce_csrf(request)
            return self.get_user(validated_token),validated_token
```

**Error:**

> CSRF token missing or incorrect.
>
> Forbidden: /photos/photo_support/

when I set `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` then all work very well.
What's the reason when I set `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` then they me throw `403 Forbidden` error.

My Frontend is ReactJS.

**TestMe.js:**

```
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
Axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
Axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

const TestMe = () => {
    ....
    const payHandle = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/photos/photo_support/', {
            data:data
        })
        .then(res => {
             console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Any update on this? Seeing the same issue with Django & axios.

Comment: @Dougyfresh Helllo dear, according to the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly) CSRF cookie as `HttpOnly` doesn’t offer any practical protection because CSRF is only to protect against cross-domain attacks. If an attacker can read the cookie via JavaScript, they’re already on the same domain as far as the browser knows, so they can do anything they like anyway. (XSS is a much bigger hole than CSRF.)

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are [reading the CSRF token from the cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-csrf-token-from-cookie) at this point. As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly), setting `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True` doesn't provide you any practical benefit so if everything works with it being set to `False`, you should probably continue to do so.

However if you still need to set it to `True`, then you will need to [read the value of the CSRF token from the hidden form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-csrf-token-from-html) as mentioned in the docs again. These snippets are from the documentation:

Read the value like so:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script>
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
</script>
```

Send it in your AJAX request like so:

```
const request = new Request(
    /* URL */,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        mode: 'same-origin' // Do not send CSRF token to another domain.
    }
);
fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    // ...
});
```

I'm not well versed in React or Axios so you may have to adapt this concept to your needs.